# jscript - getting list of files in directory

Tags: javascript, scripting

This seems like it should be easy.  I've never used JScript before and I'm looking at the JScript api provided by microsoft but no luck.  Here's what I have:

```
    var fso, tf;
fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
tf = fso.CreateTextFile("New Tracks.txt", true);
var objShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
var lib;
lib = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0,"Select Library Folder",0);
items = lib.Items()
for (i=0;i<items.Count;i++)
{
    fitem = items[i];
    tf.WriteLine(fitem.Name);
}
WScript.Echo("Done");
tf.Close();
```

I get an error about fitem.Name that it's not an object or null or something.  However, there are definitely files in that folder.

Comment: Perhaps there is another way, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `items` variable in your script holds a [`FolderItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787800.aspx) collection rather than an array. To access the collection's items, you need to use the [`Items(index)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787802.aspx) notation. So, replacing

```
fitem = items[i];
```

with

```
fitem = items.Item(i);
```

will make the script work.

Comment: Thanks!  I had just figured that out.  That's definitely what the problem was

Answer (score 3):

This works for me, I had to change the path to the file or I get access denied (win 7).

```
  <script language="JScript">
var fso, tf;
fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
tf = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\\New Tracks.txt", true);

var objShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
var lib;

lib = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0,"Select Library Folder",0);

var en = new Enumerator(lib.Items());

for (;!en.atEnd(); en.moveNext()) {
    tf.WriteLine(en.item());
}

WScript.Echo("Done");
tf.Close();
  </script>
```

Comment: For jscript the enumerator is the key here... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/language-compilers/use-jscript-javascript-traverse-collection

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can't access it like an array and have to call the Item() method.