# List local directory on Web Application

Tags: javascript, directory, activex

I have an idea a Web Application and I would need to list all files of a directory that exists on the client machine (For example C:\Temp).

I searched a lot on the Internet and as well on Stack Overflow. I couldn't find an answer on any questions that soved my problems.

I want to be able to list all files and subdirectories of a directory and if possible get the file type.

I know that this isn't able to do only with native Javascript. If there is something restricted to a browser like Firefox, like XPCOM I wouldn't mind using.

I just wanted to know what is the best approach to do this on a WEB Application. (Windows apps are not acceptable, and also don't want to rely on ActiveX since we're no planning on IE support).

We have a preference for Javascript based solutions. We really don't want to rely on Server-Side to do this. But we are opened to Server-Side suggestions.
For any server-side suggestion, we are using ASP .NET MVC.

We area looking for something similar to [jscript - getting list of files in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721119/jscript-getting-list-of-files-in-directory) but I don't want to rely on ActiveX at all. As said before a Firefox-only solution would be OK.

Answer (score 2):

In short:You can't get the control to list the files resides on local system(client machine) from browser.

Comment: The filesystem is DELIBERATELY unavailable for security reasons. You need to use Java or Flash to do this.

Comment: I know that this isn't avaiable. I'm looking for alternatives. Like Flash or Java based, even Silverlight. Just beginning a discussion about what would be the best approach

Answer (score 0):

Java applets, if signed and set up properly, can get access to the local filesystem if the user clicks allow on the popup dialog box.

Flash and Silverlight, being built by intelligent beings, do not allow you access to the local filesystem -- and if they did, they would also have a dialog pop up asking if the user trusts the web app.  Otherwise people could use it to collect all sorts of potentially dangerous information about your system.