# How to check if filename contains substring in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, filenames

I have a folder on the hard drive with files named

1. myfileone_163637
2. myfiletwo_14153535
3. myfilethree_3739284

The numbers at the end of the filenames are random.

How can I check with JavaScript if the file containing "myfilethree" in its name is present?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript+indexof

Answer (score 3):

if you have the file names you can use something like:

```
if(theFileName.indexOf('myfilethree') > -1)
{
    do your magic here because "myfilethree" is present in the name!
}
```

However, I am not aware of any way to read a directory index in javascript.

Comment: He may be using node.js, which has a module for filesystem interaction.

Comment: @Sirko node.js supports `indexOf` by all means :)

Comment: @VisioN The comment was just meant for the last sentence, which doubted a directory index function for JavaScript. Gave +1, anyway.

Comment: I know node has lots of IO stuff but node does not equal javascript, nor is it mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this: getting a list of files in a directory, and then searching them for a substring. I'll start with the sceond part, because that's easiest. Simply use `indexOf` to check for the desired string. If the result of `indexOf` is not equal to -1, you have a match:

```
if (filename.indexOf("myfilex") != -1) {
    // whatever you want to do
}
```

As to actually retrieving a list of files, you will need to use Windows Script Host and JScript. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5721119/196307) for details on that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'myfilethree';
if (str.toLowerCase().indexOf("myfilethree") >= 0)
{
    alert('File Found');
}
```

**Try This:**